# A callback for when data is received?

Tags: c, windows, linux, unix

So, my understanding is that the Kernel could receive TCP at any time, and that generally a C program asks the Kernel synchronously/asynchronously if it has data available. Would it be possible for a callback to happen in the Kernel once a certain amount of data has arrived on a socket?

This may be best asked in a separate question, but if the above is not possible, what is the most effective threading structure for NIO in C?

Comment: Did you have a look at [libevent](http://libevent.org/)?

Comment: Windows has a system that causes a window to receive messages when a socket receives info, but since calling the registering function for the first time spawns a new thread, it probably means that under the hood it's done with that thread doing sychronous waits for you.